# ios9 CNContactUI imageData

Tags: objective-c, ios9, cncontact

I want to set Contact IconImage

```
CNMutableContact *contact = [CNMutableContact new];
NSData *myImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImg);
contact.imageData = myImageData;
```

Then, my Icon looks like this:

[image: The Fact]

But, I want it like this (no "add photo", Opaque image and With edit Button)

[image]

`ABPersonSetImageData` can finish my request,but I want to use `CNcontact`.

So what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this as well. The only way I could get it to work was by splitting up the operation of adding the CNContact to the ContactStore via two saveRequests. I first saved the "empty" new contact. Then I "updated" the contact with its data.